# Bootstrap 4 navbar positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to figure out how to set position of my navbar to certain places. I want the brand name, which is "Athletics", to stay on the left and the other options to stay on the left. I tried "navbar-left",  "navbar-right", the grid system, and some CSS but nothing seemed to work. Here is a link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mcoulibaly23/9sn2kx58/
I will also post it below:

```
<htnl>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Navbar | Athletics </title>       
</head>
<body>

    <nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color:darkmagenta; font-family:Roboto;">
        <a class="navbar navbar-brand" href="#"> Athletics </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> Shop </a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> About Us </a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> Lookbook </a></li>
                <li><form class="form-inline">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" height="10">
                    <button class="btn bth-outline-success" type="Submit"> Search </button>
                </form></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your problem? All the navigation items are on the left? Do you want them to appear on the right? If you want the nav items to be displayed on the right, just just 'ml-auto' on the ul element like that:
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got you right, you want to have Brand name on left and nav items to the right on navbar?
If yes, then this class should do the trick "justify-content-end"

I've modified your code slightly with comments on where i did the corrections:

```
<!-- appropriate for html5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Navbar | Athletics </title>       
</head>
<body>

    <nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color:darkmagenta; font-family:Roboto;">
        <a class="navbar navbar-brand" href="#"> Athletics </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- add class justify-content-end to the div below to have nav-items positioned on right --> 
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> Shop </a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> About Us </a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"> Lookbook </a></li>
                <li><form class="form-inline">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" height="10">
                    <button class="btn bth-outline-success" type="Submit"> Search </button>
                </form></li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </nav>


</body>
```